# How to plot each histogram into a grid after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form

```
index       Var2     Var6
                           
 0         1          100
 1         1          123
 2         2          234
 3         2          456
 4         2          132
 5         2          354
 6         3          153
 7         4          456
 8         4          123
 9         4          125
```

I want to draw a histogram by grouping `Var2`.
According to the example above, there are 4 `Var2`. Therefore, there should be 4 histograms.
The code above is the code I used as an example.
Actually, in my data, there are 1 to 144 `Var2` and the number of `Var6` is random. How do I plot a histogram for 144?
Then, how do I do gaussian fitting and measure the full width at half maximum (FWHM)?

Comment: you could apply `.hist()` over your dataFrameGroupby object (what `.groupby(condition)` returns. So you could do `df.groupby(['Var2']).hist()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
All 144 histograms were displayed.
I have one problem.
Is there a way to display 12 horizontal and 12 vertical histograms on one page?

Answer (score 1):

Either use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with the `subplots` option or seaborn [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with `col`.

---

#### [`DataFrame.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html)

1. Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to convert `Var2` values into columns:

   ```
   pivoted = df.pivot_table(
       index=df.groupby('Var2').cumcount(),
       columns='Var2',
       values='Var6')

   # Var2      1      2      3      4
   # 0     100.0  234.0  153.0  456.0
   # 1     123.0  456.0    NaN  123.0
   # 2       NaN  132.0    NaN  125.0
   # 3       NaN  354.0    NaN    NaN
   ```
2. Use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `subplots` and `layout` to plot those columns into subplots:

   ```
   # adjust the params as needed for your real data
   pivoted.plot.hist(
       subplots=True,
       layout=(2, 2),
       figsize=(8, 8),
       sharey=True)
   ```

   [image]

---

#### [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)

- If you are open to using seaborn, use your original `df` (not pivoted) with [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) and `kind='hist'`:

  ```
  sns.histplot(
      data=df, x='Var6',
      col='Var2', col_wrap=2,
      height=3, aspect=1,
      kind='hist')
  ```

  [image]